# Merge array of keys and array of values with an exception to the mapping

Tags: php, arrays, mapping

I've got two arrays, one with IDs and one with Names:

```
$ids = [4, 13, 6, 8, 10];
$names = ['alice', 'bob', 'charles', 'david', 'elizabeth'];
```

I need to update the db so that the rows with the ids have the names in the array. Here's the tricky bit: I also have two integers:

```
$special_name = 2; // the index in $names, in this case we mean 'charles'
$special_id = 13;  // the id value
```

I don't care about which name goes to which id, except that the name with the `$special_name` should go on the `$special_id`.

What's the most elegant way to get there? All of the methods that I'm thinking of seem pretty messy. The best I've thought of is to extract out the special items from each array, and do those first, and then do the rest, perhaps building a new array like this:

```
$mapped = [];
$mapped[$special_id] = $names[$special_name];
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    if ($id != $special_id) {
        $mapped[$id] = current($names);
    }
    // advance $names pointer
    $next_name = next($names);
    if ($next_name == $special_name) {
        next($names);
    }
}
```

I haven't tested that yet (I'm about to) but it's meant to produce something like:

```
$mapped = [
    13 => 'charles',
    4 => 'alice',
    6 => 'bob',
    8 => 'david',
    10 => 'elizabeth'
];
```

and then running through that to do the actual update. Got a better idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it wasn't for the special Ids, you could have just [array_combine](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)'d the two arrays. Here is how I think to have solved the issue:

Setup

```
$ids = array(4, 13, 6, 8, 10);
$names = array('alice', 'bob', 'charles', 'david', 'elizabeth');
$specialNameIndex = 2;
$specialId = 13;
```

Solution

```
  $result = array($specialId => $names[$specialNameIndex]);
  unset($ids[array_search($specialId, $ids)], 
        $names[$specialNameIndex]);
  $result += array_combine($ids, $names);
```

Result

```
print_r($result);
Array
(
    [13] => charles
    [4] => alice
    [6] => bob
    [8] => david
    [10] => elizabeth
)
```

Comment: Incredible. I was about to post line for line the exact same solution, except feeding 2 args to unset(). creepy lol

Comment: @chris even with the same variable names? Oo :D

Comment: I thought about using unset, too, but array_combine slipped my mind. That feels a bit better. Cool, didn't know you could add arrays like that. Thx.

Comment: ah crap! array_combine requires that both arrays have the same number of elements, which might not necessarily be the case. Either could be longer, we're only mapping as many as we can. Gah!

Comment: @Gordon, no, I used the op's variable names.

Comment: @sprugman you could array_pad them to an equal length, but I still fail to see what this exercise is for anyway. What usecase are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Gordon: It's complex and not really worth going into all the details, but I'm trying to overwrite the names in the users table with some data from somewhere else, and I need to make sure the "special" ones get linked. And like I said, either list could be longer. In any case, I used a loop instead of array_combine, which works fine. I gave you the vote even though it doesn't fully solve my actual use case because you answered the question that I asked, and gave me some good ideas...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) and then set/append your special values:

```
$mapped = array_combine($ids, $names);
$mapped[$special_id] = $names[$special_name];
```

Comment: This overwrites the existing name at special ID (bob) and then you had charles twice in the array. Also, $special_id is the index of $names and not the name itself.

Comment: This answer is provably incorrect and should not have a positive score. https://3v4l.org/tl2pS Ideally it should be self-deleted because it has earned points while never being correct.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer uses very few function calls to populate the desired result. The approach declares the first associative element in the result according to the special conditions, then removes those elements from the input arrays, then appends the remaining data via `array_combine()` and the union operator (`+`).

A less efficient alternative would be to move the specially nominated elements to the front of their respective arrays before calling `array_combine()` on the reconfigured arrays.

---

1. Move an element to the front of its indexed array by its value (when it is guaranteed to exist):

   ```
   unset($ids[array_search(13, $ids)]);
   array_unshift($ids, $specialId);
   ```
2. Move an element to the front of its indexed array by its index/position (when it is guaranteed to exist):

   ```
   array_unshift(
       $names,
       array_splice($names, 2, 1)[0]
   );
   ```

---

If you don't want to `unset()` or `array_unshift()` on the journey to the desired result in this question, the returned array from `array_splice()` (the targeted element) can be merged to the front of each respective mutated array inside of an `array_combine()` call.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/SZCXj))

```
var_export(
    array_combine(
        array_merge(array_splice($ids, array_search(13, $ids), 1), $ids),
        array_merge(array_splice($names, 2, 1), $names)
    )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you use the default indexes you can use `foreach()` on `keys($ids)` to get the indexes so that you can iterate through both arrays at once. Just compare the value of the current index of `$ids` and use the alternate index of `$names` when appropriate.

Comment: either my comment to @henasraf applies to you as well, or I'm not understanding your solution. Can you provide a bit more (pseudo-)code?

Comment: This no implementation hint could have been a comment under the question.